# Can I enter Mexico using a Schengen business visa issued by Germany?

Tags: schengen, germany, mexico, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani national and I have Schengen business visa issued by Germany. I was supposed to travel to Germany for training but it was postponed.

Now I am planning to go to Mexico, flying from Saudi Arabia, via Frankfurt, to Cancun.

I have never used the German Schengen visa for the purpose it was issued. Can I use it to enter Mexico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [appears](https://consulmex2.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico) that Mexico offers visa-free entry for tourism/business/transit for holders of **valid unexpired** visas for (among other places) the Schengen area.

If your Schengen visa is still valid, you should be fine. There's no indication that Mexican authorities will attempt to make their own investigation into whether the Schengen visa *should* have been issued originally. If they wanted to do that, they would have an actual visa requirement of their own instead.

Basically they're using "able to get a Schengen visa" as a proxy for "doesn't fit the profile of an economic migrant", since a known tough consular service must have determined that in order to issue the visa (or, in cruder terms: "would have better options than Mexico if they wanted to be illegal immigrants somewhere *anyway*"), and concluding from it that it's probably safe to let you in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Henning. It is now clear to me that entry to mexico should not be a problem but i am still concern about the German Authorities. Since i got the visa for the purpose to visit Germany and now i am going to mexico but German airport will be my transit point. I want to know if there can be an objection raised by the authorities at the German Airport about the change of plan. Also, someone told me that one can only enter to mexico on a multiple entry schengen visa. Is it true?

Comment: @Adnan: Since you're both arriving and departing on non-Schengen flights, you will not have any occasion to meet any border guards at Frankfurt at all. (And even if you did, if the visa is still valid, how would they know you're not still planning to use it _later_?)

Comment: All I know about Mexico's policy is in the page I linked to. That doesn't say anything about needing the visa to be multiple-entry. The "someone" you got your information from may be confusing it with the rules in Romaina and Bulgaria, where _multiple-entry_ Schengen visas exempt you from the visa requirement.

Comment: @ Henning: You have helped clear all my doubts. all my questions are answered and i Thank you for that. I Will surely post my experience later.